# Check whether diagonals are the same value

Tags: prolog

I am trying to write a predicate to remove outer check whether inter diagonal are the same value(int) in prolog
For example:

```
same_Diagonal([[0,11,54,45],[16,1,6,9],[35,7,1,5],[27,3,9,1]])
```

it is

```
    [0,11,54,45]
    [16,1,6,9]
    [35,7,1,5]
    [27,3,9,1]
```

first, we remove outer part, then get

```
[1,6,9]
[7,1,5]
[3,9,1]
```

and get the head of first element of first list, then do recursively.

```
[1,5]
[9,1]
```

i have successfully remove the outer part, because when I type

```
withoutHead([[0,11,54,45],[16,1,6,9],[35,7,1,5],[27,3,9,1]],X).
```

it can show successfully

```
X = [[1, 6, 9], [7, 1, 5], [3, 9, 1]].
```

but i fail when compare the diagonal value, This is my code

```
% withoutHead(+ ListOfList, -ListOfList)
% parameter1: the ListOfList is input
% parameter2: the ListOfList process output
withoutHead([HeadRow|TailRow],Squares):-
maplist(removeHead,TailRow,Squares).

% removeHead(+List, -List)
% parameter1: the List is each row
% parameter2: the List is tail of each row
removeHead([Head|Tail], Tail).


same_Diagonal([HeadRow|TailRow]):-
    withoutHead([HeadRow|TailRow],[[Diagonal|Tail]|Back]),
    same_Diagonal(Back).
```

and I want to it return "true" when i type a right input, but it still give "false".
Anyone could tell me what is the problem?

Comment: `same_Diagonal` doesn't have any base case. Also, it doesn't seem to be actually checking anything about the diagonal elements...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The predicate must unify the upper-left value with all other diagonals.

```
same_diagonal([],_).
same_diagonal([[UpperLeft|_]|NextRows], Diagonal) :-
    Diagonal = UpperLeft,
    without_head(NextRows, SquareMatrix),    
    same_diagonal(SquareMatrix, Diagonal).
```

Or, you could define `diagonal` such that it backtracks over all diagonals in a matrix:

```
diagonal([[UpperLeft|_]|_], UpperLeft).
diagonal([_ | NextRows], Diagonal) :-
    without_head(NextRows, SquareMatrix),
    diagonal(SquareMatrix, Diagonal).

[eclipse]: diagonal([[0, 11, 54, 45], [16, 1, 6, 9], [35, 7, 1, 5], [27, 3, 9, 1]], D).

D = 0
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 1, maybe more) ? ;

D = 1
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 2, maybe more) ? ;

D = 1
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 3, maybe more) ? ;

D = 1
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 4, maybe more) ? ;

No (0.00s cpu)
```

And that could be combined with `setof/3`, which prunes duplicates results, to check whether all diagonals are the same, with `setof(D,diagonal(..., D),[_])`.

Answer (score 3):

Using `findall/3` and `nth1/3`, build a list `[X1, ..., Xn]`, where `Xi` is the i-th item of the i-th list in `M`, and get its tail `D`. Then,  using `maplist/2`, check if all items in `D` are the same `X`.

```
same_diagonal(M) :-
    findall(X, (nth1(I,M,L), nth1(I,L,X)), [_|D]),
    maplist(=(X), D).


?- same_diagonal([[0,11,54,45],[16,1,6,9],[35,7,1,5],[27,3,9,1]]).
true.

?- same_diagonal([[0,11,54,45],[16,1,6,9],[35,7,1,5],[27,3,9,9999]]).
false.
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be useful here to split the program into two predicates:

1. `diag/2` that generates the diagonal for a given list; and
2. `are_same/1` that checks if the values are all the same.

The advantage is that we can later *reuse* both predicates for different applications.

We can implement the `diag/2` as follows:

```
diag(M, D) :-
    diag(M, 0, D).

diag([], _, []).
diag([R|Rs], I, D) :-
    (  nth0(I, R, X)
    -> D = [X|Ds],
       I1 is I+1,
       diag(RS, I1, Ds)
    ;  D = []
    ).
```

This works with non-square matrices as well.

The `are_same/1` can be implemented as:

```
are_same([]).
are_same([H|T]) :-
    maplist(==(H), T).
```

So now we can combine these to:

```
same_diag(M) :-
    diag(M, D),
    are_same(D).
```

The above thus works on both "*0×0 matrices*" and *non-square* matrices.